# How to interpret a synax error 1064 in mariadb/mysql

Tags: mysql, compiler-errors, mariadb, syntax-error

Consider the following sql query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION spell_number (integer a) RETURNS string
BEGIN
  ...
END;
```

This returns the generic syntax  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near string"

Would it be possible to receive an error such as the following? :

> expected a valid type, encountered 'string' instead

Comment: It would be possiible, if somebody developed this feature in mysql. Until then, we are stuck with these really unhelpul error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the parse error 1064 is descriptive: It tells you where the parser found an error and in which line:

```
$ perror 1064
MySQL error code 1064 (ER_PARSE_ERROR): %s near '%-.80s' at line %d
```

In your example, the string behind near seems to be empty (= ''). This happens if the parser reached the end of a SQL statement but needs more data. This usually happens if you try to create a procedure or function in command line client without using a delimiter:

The default delimiter in command line client is semicolon (;). The command line client parses the CREATE function and sends the first part until delimiter to the server. Since now the CREATE statement is incomplete, the parser reaches end of statement but expects more data.

Example:

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE FUNCTION test (a integer) RETURNS integer
    -> BEGIN
    ->    SET a=a*2;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
MariaDB [test]> delimiter //
MariaDB [test]> CREATE FUNCTION test (a integer) RETURNS integer
    -> BEGIN
    ->    SET a=a*2;
    ->    RETURN a;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

And now a descriptive error message:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test1 (a integer) RETURNS integer
    -> BEGIN
    ->    "This should return a descriptive error message";
    ->    RETURN a;
    -> END//
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"This should return a descriptive error message";
```

Comment: Another case of `... near '' at line ...` is unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Rick: All cases with an uncomplete statement  Comments which are unclosed.... Still curoius why my answer get a downvote - anything fals with it?!

Comment: Beat me.  (I canceled it with an upvote.)  I wish people would read the 1064 message -- it is _extremely_ good at point right before or after the offending token.

Comment: C compilers like gcc for example return a very similar error: "Unexpected end of file" which is a little bit more descriptive.